# Migrated data with Special Characters Counted as 2 Characters in DB2 Linux

Tags: db2, db2-luw

We are currently migrating data from DB2 10.1 AIX to DB2 11.1 Linux. Since we are using some features like versioning/history tables and rowchangetimestamps, db2move is not an option for some tables. As a result we do manual export and load for some tables.

The problem arrises for data having special character such as "Ñ".

> Sample Data
>
> PIÑATA

The AIX DB2 10.1 Counts the length for this as 6 characters and it fits fine to VARCHAR(6) columns. But when I load this to DB2 Linux 11.1, this is counted as 7 characters, thus data is truncated.

I tried CASTING this as VARCHAR(6) but the data is still truncated. I hope someone can point me to a possible solution.

Comment: What are the code pages of both databases? Single byte for 10.1 and utf-8 for 11.1?

Comment: Hi the codepage for 10.1 is 1252  and codeset is IBM-1252 while 11.1 is code page is 1208 and Codeset is UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every character needs 1 byte in a single-byte database, but it may need from 1 to 4 bytes in a UTF-8 database.
When you specify VARCHAR(`N`) for a column, `N` is defined in `string units`.
`OCTETS` means bytes, and `CODEUNITS32` means characters.
In your case `N` probably is OCTETS, and since `Ñ` character requires 2 bytes (OCTETS), then whole string length in the UTF-8 database is 7.
[Character strings](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008470.html)

Comment: Is there a way that I can make the database behave similar to when it was in AIX? The problem is some data are being truncated because of this.

Comment: Should i just move my aix 10.1 db to 11.1 before i migrate to linux or it does not matter?

Comment: Use `CREATE DATABASE MYDB ... USING CODESET 1252 TERRITORY XX`. You can get your 10.1 database territory code with the following command: `db2 get db cfg for my101db | grep -i terr`. [Supported territory codes and code pages](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0004565.html)